# Limit of $cos$ to $e$

Tags: limits

What do with it? I try to resolve through L'Hopital, but it's so difficult for first course.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{e^{\sin(2x)}-1}$$

Thanks

Comment: hint : $$(e^u)'=u' \times e^u\\e^{sin(2x)} \to 2cos(2x) e^{sin2x}$$

Comment: without $\frac{d}{dx}$ ?

Comment: are you ok with Taylor series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's a pretty basic application of l'Hôpital:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{e^{\sin(2x)}-1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\pi} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{\sin(2x)}-1 \right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi} \frac{-\frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{x }{2}\right)}{2 e^{ \sin (2 x)} \cos (2 x)}= \frac{-1}{4}$$

Comment: without $\frac{d}{dx}$

Comment: This is basic calculus.

Comment: Use :$$ e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+\frac{u^3}{3!}+\frac{u^4}{4!}+...$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{e^{\sin(2x)}-1}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{\sin(2x)}-1\right)}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2}}{2\cos(2x)e^{\sin(2x)}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}-\frac{e^{-\sin(2x)}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{4\cos(2x)}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{-\sin(2x)}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\cos(2x)}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{e^{-\sin(2x)}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\cos(2x)}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{-\sin(2\cdot\pi)}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\cos(2\cdot\pi)}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{-0}\cdot 1}{1}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 1}{1}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{-0}\cdot 1}{1}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1}=-\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{e^{sin(2x)}-1}=\\
\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{(1+sin2x+sin^22x+\frac{sin^32x}{2!}+...)-1}=\\
\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{sin2x(1+sin2x+\frac{sin2x}{2}+...)}=\\
\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{{\color{Red} {2sinx cosx}}(1+sin2x+\frac{sin2x}{2}+...)}=\\
\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})}{{\color{Red} {2(2sin(\frac{x}{2})cos(\frac{x}{2})) cosx}}(1+sin2x+\frac{sin2x}{2}+...)}$$then cancel ${\color{Red} {cos\frac{x}{2}}}$ so $$\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{1}{{\color{Red} {4sin(\frac{x}{2}) cosx}}(1+sin2x+\frac{sin2x}{2}+...)}=\\\frac{1}{-4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\quad$ There are certain famous limits which are usually taught in school long before more

advanced techniques, like l'Hopital's rule, are introduced. Among them are, for instance,

$\lim\limits_{t\to0}~\dfrac{\sin t}t=1~$ and $~\lim\limits_{u\to0}~\dfrac{e^u-1}u=1.~$ Since $\sin(k\pi)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z,$ we have

> $$\lim_{x\to\pi}~\dfrac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac x2\bigg)}{e^{\sin(2x)}-1}~=~\lim_{x\to\pi}~\dfrac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac x2\bigg)}{\quad\dfrac{e^{\sin(2x)}-1}{\sin(2x)}\cdot\sin(2x)\quad}~=~\lim_{x\to\pi}~\dfrac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac x2\bigg)}{1\cdot\sin(2x)}~.$$

Letting $x=\pi-y,$ and using the fact that $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-t\bigg)=\sin t$ in conjunction

with $\sin(2\pi-u)=-\sin u,$ we have $~\lim\limits_{x\to\pi}~\dfrac{\cos\bigg(\dfrac x2\bigg)}{\sin(2x)}~=-\lim\limits_{y\to0}~\dfrac{\sin\bigg(\dfrac y2\bigg)}{\sin(2y)}~=$

$=-\lim\limits_{y\to0}~\dfrac{\quad\dfrac{\sin\big(y/2\big)}{y/2}\cdot y/2\quad}{\dfrac{\sin(2y)}{2y}\cdot2y}~=-\lim\limits_{y\to0}~\dfrac{1\cdot y/2}{1\cdot2y}~=~-\dfrac14~.$